# YouTube Player Api Reloads Video from start on switching to full screen

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I was trying to integrate the Youtube player api in my app. But when I switch to full screen there are a couple of problems that occur:

1. The video reloads from the beginning.
2. On pressing the back button in full screen mode, the app is forced into landscape orientation.

public class YouTubeVideoElement extends Element implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

```
private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "MY_KEY";
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    private YouTubePlayerFragment playerFragment;
    private View playerView;
    private ViewGroup viewFrame;
    public State state;
    private Dialog errorDialog;
    private Context context;

    public YouTubeVideoElement(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }


    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewGroup getView() {
        return viewFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewGroup populateView(Context context, JsonObject data, Map<String, String> style) {

        viewFrame = new FrameLayout(context);
        playerView = new FrameLayout(context);
        playerView.setId(R.id.player_view);
        playerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewFrame.addView(playerView, -1, -1);
        playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playerFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
        playerFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.player_view, playerFragment).commit();
        return viewFrame;
    }

    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getLayoutParams() {
        return layoutParams;
    }

    public YouTubeVideoElement setLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams) {
        this.layoutParams = layoutParams;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        Log.d("xxx", "onInitSuccess YTP");
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {

        Log.d("xxx", "onInitFailure YTP");
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog((Activity) context, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            //String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u solve this issue?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 15):

Please try and update this in your AndroidManifest file:

```
 <activity
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
  android:name="com.example.yourClassThatHandlesTheYoutubePlayer">
```

> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When
>   a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down
>   and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this
>   attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the
>   activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is
>   called.

From the [official android guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Comment: As you can see above the youtubeplayer is not in an activity directly. And I don't want to change the orientation of the activity it is in indirectly(since it is a part of my main activity)
Is there no other workaround except changing the Manifest file?

Comment: @A.B. What do you pass its constructor as context? I'm thinking of this    public YouTubeVideoElement(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

Comment: The context of the activity which has a fragment inside which the YouTubeVideoElement goes. I don't want to make a change in the manifest in that activity.